# Theme without responsiveness

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

I am migrating my application to Liferayv 6.2 but I wantt to make the theme non responsive. How can I do that?

Comment: You should add an explanation, why you would like a theme that looks broken on small devices.

Comment: Why would you want to disable the responsiveness? There's no need to bother, if you don't access your portal on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new theme based on the classic theme and get rid of twitter bootstrap and all the media queries.

Or create an unstyled theme and put all your styling in it.

If you have no idea how to create a theme: use the maven artifact or download Liferay Developer Studio (eclipse).